# Not every point is recurrent for a hyperbolic toral automorphism

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, topological-dynamics

Let $A: \mathbb{T}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{T}^2 $ is a hyperbolic toral automorphism induced by an invertible integer matrix $A$ with no eigenvalues of modulus $1$, we say a point $x \in \mathbb{T}^2$ is recurrent, if there exists a sequence of natural numbers $n_k \rightarrow \infty$ (as $k \rightarrow \infty$) such that $A^{n_k} x \rightarrow x$. Then an exercise (Brin and Stuck's *Introduction to Dynamical Systems*, Exercise 2.1.6 on p.31) says that there exists some non-recurrent points in $\mathbb{T}^2$.

I know that all rational points are periodic, hence recurrent. But I do not have an idea for the construction of a non-recurrent point. Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a low-brow argument:

Consider the eigenspaces $S$ and $U$ of the matrix $A$, corresponding to the eigenvalues with modulus less than $1$ and greater than $1$, respectively. Take small segments $S_\epsilon$ and $U_\epsilon$ (of positive length) of the eigenspaces around the origin; for $\epsilon$ small enough the product $\mathcal{S}_{0,\epsilon}\times \mathcal{U}_{0,\epsilon}$ of their images under the quotient map $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{T}^2$ will be a neighborhood of $0$ in the torus. The set $\mathcal{S}_{0,\epsilon}$ is mapped (strictly) into itself under $A$, and any element in $\mathcal{S}_{0,\epsilon}\setminus\{0\}$ converges to $0$ exponentially fast, hence can not be recurrent.

Comment: Thank you! I have considered the expanding direction, but ignored the contracting direction...